# Name for (maximum+minimum)/2 and relationship to average?

Tags: mean, terminology, extreme-value

Is there a common name for $c := \frac{max(X)+min(X)}{2}$? What is the relationship between $\tilde{x} := Avg(X)$ and $c$? What metrics or information can I derive from $\tilde{x}$ and $c$?

If I have $C := \{c_{i}|1 \leq i \leq \frac{|X|}{2}; c_{i} := \frac{max_{i}(X)+min_{i}(X)}{2}\}$ where $max_{i}$ is the i-th maximum and $min_{i}$ is the i-th minimum ($max_{2}$ would be the second largest element). What can I derive from $C$? $|X|$ here means the amount of samples/values in $X$.

Comment: The quantity you refer to is called the midrange. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range

Comment: $E(c) = E(\bar X)$ if the distribution is symmetric. Otherwise $E(c)$ and $E(\bar X)$ can be used to indicate degree of skewness of the distribution of $X$. BTW, what is $|X|$?

Comment: $|X|$ is the number of elements in $X$.

Comment: Maybe you should add |X| into your question. At least, I think it is kind of absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

Partially answered in comments:

> The quantity you refer to is called the midrange. See:
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range

```
- compbiostats
```